# Where should I put class definitions that will be used by multiple Android Activities? (Java)

Tags: java, android, class

The problem:

- I have an app that has multiple Activities
- I need to pass objects between the activities.
- Where should I put the class definition?
- These objects will be used all around the app, and I'd like a centralized place where I can view all the class definitions that will be used around the app. For things like "user" objects and things like that.

Writing in C/C++, I would put the definitions in a .h header file. But Java doesn't support header files.
I've seen some other solutions on stackoverflow suggesting I use packages, but it seems like I need to create the packages in the java directory on my machine.
I'm hoping to store the class definitions in the app files.

Comment: What do you mean by _"store the class definitions in the app files."_?

Comment: I think he means have the definitions and code inline in 1 file

Comment: Suppose you have an app like Spotify. I'm assuming there's something like a "song" class, for "song objects, containing, Title, Artist, Album, Length, and other info like that.
Where would you make the class definition for the "song" object? 
I assume it would be bad practice to define at the top of the first class that uses it? 

I have read that I could use Java packages?
This tutorial says java packages are stored in the java directory of the machine:
https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_packages.asp

I was hoping I create the definition within the code of the app.